# For α and β ∈ Sn, define α ∼ β if there exists a σ ∈ $S_n$ such that $σασ^{−1}$ = β. Show that ∼ is an equivalence relation on $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, equivalence-relations, symmetric-groups

My attempt is below. Could I please get feedback on it. I am not so sure that it is correct.

Let α,β,σ ∈$S_n$.
Since $S_n$ is a group, we know that it contains an identity.
Let e be the identity. So, $\sim$ is reflexive since $\alpha = e \alpha e^{-1} = e \alpha = \alpha e^{-1} = \alpha$.
Since σ ∈ $S_n$ we know that there is a σ such that $σασ^{−1} = β$.
Further, because $S_n$ is a group, it must contain an inverse.
So, $α = σ^{−1}σασ^{−1}σ = σ^{−1}βσ$.
We now have $α = σ^{−1}βσ$ and $σασ^{−1} = β$, proving symmetry.
For transitivity, we must show that if α ∼ β and β ∼ c, then α ∼ c.
We already know that α ∼ β from above.
We still need to show that $σβσ^{−1} = c$.
Substituting in for β, $σ_1(σ_2ασ_2^{-1})σ_1^{-1} = (σ_1σ_2)α(σ_2^{-1} σ_1^{-1})$.
So, $σ_1^{-1} σ_2^{-1} = |σ_2σ_1|^{-1}$ as we are required to have a σ that shows $σβσ^{-1} = c$.

Comment: I am not too confident in the part proving transitivity

Comment: Honestly I do not understand a single line of this proof. To prove reflexivity for example you need to prove that $\alpha\sim\alpha$ for every $\alpha$. This is the case because you can pick $\sigma=e$ in the definition. But this is not what you seem to be saying. Also, “$S_n$ is reflexive” does not make sense. What is reflexive is the relation $\sim$, etc.

Comment: yeah, i've been making some edits to the proof because it also didn't make sense to me after rereading it. Thanks! I will rewrite ~ as being reflexive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Reflexivity:** Observe that for all $\alpha\in S_n$: $\alpha=e\cdot\alpha\cdot e^{-1}$, for $e$ the identity element of $S_n$. Thus $\alpha\sim\alpha$.
- **Symmetry:** Suppose $\alpha\sim\beta$, then there is $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\alpha=\sigma\beta\sigma^{-1}$, so we can conclude that $\beta=\sigma^{-1}\alpha\sigma=\sigma^{-1}\alpha(\sigma^{-1})^{-1}$, so $\beta\sim\alpha$.
- **Transitivity:** Suppose $\alpha\sim\beta$ and $\beta\sim\gamma$. Then there exists $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$ such that
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  \alpha=\sigma\beta\sigma^{-1} &(1)\\ 
  \beta=\tau\gamma\tau^{-1} &(2)
  \end{cases}
  $$
  so by replacing $\beta$ from equation $(2)$ in equation $(1)$ we will get $\alpha=\sigma\tau\gamma\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}=\sigma\tau\gamma(\sigma\tau)^{-1}$.

Comment: Is showing $\alpha \sim \gamma$ as simple as substituting the definition of $\beta$ from part (2) into part (1)?

Comment: yes, if we will denote $\delta=\sigma\tau$, then it follows that $\alpha=\delta\gamma\delta^{-1}$, so by defintion $\alpha\sim\gamma$

Comment: Cool! Very simple and beautiful.

Comment: Is it wrong to suppose that $\sigma \in S_n$ at the very beginning of my proof?

Comment: Well, you need to specify what $\sigma$ means, if you introduced it as a general element of the group and than gave it a specific quantity it is a bit problematic. Also  the statement  "Since $\sigma \in S_n$ we know that there is a $\sigma$ such that..." is bit problematic in the same way. Try to avoid  giving the same symbol a few meanings.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that I was doing that. I thought that $\sigma \alpha \sigma^{-1} = \beta$ was an assumption that I could make from the start. I see now that it is a consequence of $\alpha \sim \beta$.